# conversion from 'long' to 'VARTYPE', possible loss of data

Tags: com, visual-c++

On migrating a VC++ 6.0 developed code to Visual studio 2008, I got the below warnings

> > warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'VARTYPE', possible loss of data

Code Snippet:

```
STDMETHODIMP CTextFileParser::FormatString(long lTargetType, BSTR szFormat, BSTR      szInput, VARIANT *value) // Has Definition of lTargetType
CComVariant vErg(szSource.c_str()); // Definition of vErg
vErg.vt = lTargetType; // C4244
```

> > warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'long' to 'VARTYPE', possible loss of data

Code Snippet:

```
STDMETHODIMP CField::get_ContentWithType(long lType, VARIANT *pVal) // Has Definition of lType
{
 HRESULT hRC;
 CComVariant oNewValue(m_content);           // Definition of oNewValue
 hRC = oNewValue.ChangeType(lType, NULL);    // C4244
 if (SUCCEEDED(hRC)) oNewValue.Detach(pVal);
 return hRC;
}
```

I'm unable to fix this warning?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VARTYPE is a 16 bit integer type:

```
WTYPES.H:typedef unsigned short VARTYPE;
```

You will be wanting a `static_cast<VARTYPE>()` in there.